# How to dynamically create an environment variable?

Tags: powershell, puppet

I am using powershell script to set some environment variable--

```
$env:FACTER_Variable_Name = $Variable_Value
```

FACTER is for using these in the puppet scripts.

My problem is - the variable name and variable value both are dynamic and getting read from a text file.

I am trying to use

```
$env:FACTER_$Variable_Name = $Variable_Value
```

But $ is not acceptable syntax. When I enclose it in double quotes, the variable value is not getting passed. Any suggestion how to use it dynamically.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: using `$($Variable_Value)` can help?

Comment: See my answer to this question: [Reuse of environment variables in Path](http://superuser.com/questions/882837/reuse-of-environment-variables-in-path)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TestVariable", "Test value.", "User")`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx)

This syntax allows expressions in the place of "TestVariable", and should be enough to create a profile-local environment variable. The third parameter can be "Process", this makes new vars visible in `Get-ChildItem env:` or "Machine" - this required administrative rights to set the variable. To retrieve a variable set like this, use `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("TestVariable", "User")` (or matching scope if you choose another).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vesper.. But will it not create a permanent variable instead of temporary one?

Comment: I guess process level should create a temoporary one ?

Comment: If your variable would be of user scope, it'll be "permanent", at least reboot-presistent, until nullified. If your variable will be of process scope, it'll be temporary but available if you launch a process (`cmd.exe` tested) from within Powershell process where this variable was declared.

Answer (score 19):

On Powershell 5, to set dynamically an environment variable in the current shell I use [Set-Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/set-item?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
>$VarName="hello"
>Set-Item "env:$VarName" world
```

once the variable is set, you can get its value like so:

```
>$env:hello
world
```

and of course to persist the variable I use C#  `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("$VarName", "world", "User")`

Comment: Using `Set-Item` is the best answer here.  The advantage of `Set-Item` is that it is cross platform and will work on Linux machines running PowerShell 7.

The `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` approach will only work for windows machines since it relies on a .NET Framework class.

Comment: But you could install .Net Framework on your linux tho? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download idk if I should edit my answer. on linux env, I use zsh, and on mac fish shell :P

Comment: How do you get this variable again then?

Comment: using $env:<var name> like in the example. I updated my answer to make it easier to read but the info was already there. I hope you found the solution already; I just saw your msg now

Answer (score 12):

In pure PowerShell, something like this:

```
$Variable_Name = "foo"
$FullVariable_Name = "FACTER_$Variable_Name"
$Variable_Value = "Hello World"
New-Item -Name $FullVariable_Name -value $Variable_Value -ItemType Variable -Path Env:
```

I'm using the New-Item cmdlet to add a new variable, just have to specify the `-itemtype` and `-path`

Comment: This is also a good answer.   due to its cross platform support

Comment: using Set-Item is cross platforms too and it has the convenience of being shorter